# Download an Excel document built with class CL_XLSX_DOCUMENT

Tags: abap

My program below creates an Excel document built with the class CL_XLSX_DOCUMENT, which contains two sheets.

How can I download the Excel document on my laptop ?

```
lo_worksheetpart ?= lo_workbookpart->get_worksheetparts( )->get_part( lv_line_no_loop ).
lo_worksheetpart_1 ?= lo_workbookpart->add_worksheetpart( ).

lv_sheetxml = lo_worksheetpart->get_data(  ).
lv_sheetxml_2 = lo_worksheetpart_1->get_data(  ).

lo_sharedstringspart = lo_workbookpart->get_sharedstringspart( ).
lv_sharedxml = lo_sharedstringspart->get_data( ).

"Parse and replace
if lt_nameval is not initial.
lv_resultxml = update_shared_string_1(
  EXPORTING
    iv_xml             = lv_sharedxml
    iv_node            = co_shared_string
    it_nameval         = lt_nameval ).

"write new excel
lo_sharedstringspart->feed_data( lv_resultxml ).

lv_resultxml = update_sheet_data_1(
  EXPORTING
    iv_xml             = lv_sheetxml
    iv_node            = co_sheet_data
    it_days            = lt_days
    it_nameval         = lt_nameval ).

"write new excel
lo_worksheetpart->feed_data( lv_resultxml ).
endif.
```

Comment: I have edited your question to contain more precise elements, could you verify whether it still corresponds to your question, please? Feel free to directly edit it if needed.

Comment: Please post complete code. From the fragment you provided no one can guess the data types the variables have and they are essential to answer your question.

Comment: what is the type of `lv_resultxml`?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
DATA: 
      lv_fsize          TYPE i,
      lt_data           TYPE tsfixml,
      lv_resultxml      TYPE xstring.

CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
  EXPORTING
    buffer        = lv_resultxml
  IMPORTING
    output_length = lv_fsize
  TABLES
    binary_tab    = lt_data.

CALL METHOD cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download
  EXPORTING
    bin_filesize            = lv_fsize
    filetype                = 'BIN'
    filename                = 'C:\Temp\filename.xlsx
  CHANGING
    data_tab                = lt_data
```